# How to change comboboxes background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate

How do I change out my combobox background I had been able to do it for the items with a new itemtemplate 
but not for the combobox itself as brush properties not working for that
[i want to change this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APhqW.png)

combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Bil_box" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="57,33,968,799" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="151" Height="40" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#FF303030" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cmbTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Margin="0 5 0 5" Height="30">
        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Billed}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding bilmærke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF00FB0B"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Krydsmål}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF00FB0B"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Item you're looking for is a `Border` control called `templateRoot`

You first have to edit a Template for your ComboBox (edit a copy if youve haven't already got one). Then look for a `ToggleButton` control called `toggleButton`.

Right click and Edit this Template (edit current) and you should be able to find the border I mentioned above. Change the `Background` and you're good to go.

The code is too long to post (due to the size of the Templates) but here's a snippet of the relevant bit (I've changed the background to **Red**)

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
```

Comment: are there any other way to do that since you can only do that one without PresentationFramework.Aero2 wich are giving me some errors on win 7 since is only a win8 and above feature